# RPS- Creating a tally with end result in Python

Tags: python

My teacher wants us to create a basic rock paper scissors game that loops until the user ends the game, at which point the program will add up all the wins/losses/ties (of the player) and display it. Here is what I have so far, but I cannot figure out how to create that running tally in the background that will spit out the calculation at the end. (The bottom part of the win/loss/tie product is written by my teacher. It must print this way.)

```py
def main():

import random

Wins = 0 

Ties = 0 

Losses = 0 

while True:

    user_action = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")

    possible_actions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

    computer_action = random.choice(possible_actions)

    print(f"\nYou chose {user_action}, computer chose {computer_action}.\n")

    if user_action == computer_action:
        print(f"Both players selected {user_action}. It's a tie!")
    elif user_action == "rock":
        if computer_action == "scissors":
            print("Rock smashes scissors! You win!")
        else:
            print("Paper covers rock! You lose.")
    elif user_action == "paper":
        if computer_action == "rock":
            print("Paper covers rock! You win!")
        else:
            print("Scissors cuts paper! You lose.")
    elif user_action == "scissors":
        if computer_action == "paper":
            print("Scissors cuts paper! You win!")
        else:
            print("Rock smashes scissors! You lose.")

    play_again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
    if play_again.lower() != "y":
        print("Good Game!")
        print("Wins \t Ties \t Losses")
        print("---- \t ---- \t ------")
        print(wins, "\t", ties , "\t", losses)import random
```

Comment: Here's how to [format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on the site

Answer (score 1):

Where you are printing out wether the user has tied, lost or won you can simply increment the related value.

The text may not be displaying together due to the text not being the same size, add more /t to the strings and it should line up.